# Poor UITableView Scrolling Performance issue iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that contains more than 20 rows, each UITableViewCell contains a UITextView which I can set different UIFont, alignment and colour. When I scroll down or up there is a choppy or lagging during the scrolling, when I remove the font and text colours and alignment everything become perfect. Did Apple changes the way of redrawing text in iOS 7? This did not happen with the previous iOS versions.

instruments shows that the time consumed at `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`

-- UPDATE Add Code

```
if (unit.fontName != nil ) {
            textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:unit.fontName size:unit.fontSize.floatValue];
        }
        if (unit.fontColor) {
            textView.textColor=[self convertString:unit.fontColor];
        }
        else {
            textView.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
        }
        if ([unit.fontSize floatValue] !=0) {
            textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:textView.font.fontName size:[unit.fontSize floatValue]];
        }
        if (unit.textAlignment) {

            switch ([summaryUnit.textAlignment intValue]) {
                case 0:
                    textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
                    break;

                case 1:
                    textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Show your code. Do you have set configurations, or every cell is different?

Comment: Do you have custom UITableViewCell class for your tableView?

Comment: @RajSubbiah Yes I have a custom cell

Comment: @Wain one Custom cell but the font, text alignment, colours different for each cell

Comment: Use instruments to profile the scrolling and see what is taking the time

Comment: @Wain instruments show the time consumed  at dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:

Comment: Do you have code in `prepareForReuse`? Can you see more detail from instruments?

Comment: @Wain no i don't use prepareForReuse, this issue consistent only when the textview have large text

Comment: Try setting the text to `nil` in `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: @Wain still nothing changed

Comment: There seem to be a lot of method calls that could perhaps be computed once and saved - things like [self convertString] and the font lookup

Comment: I don't think you've given us enough info to help you. Please add a screen-shot of your time profiler output and your full 'tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Comment: @RoboticCat I post a screenshot of instruments with 'tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:' code

Comment: Comments: `1.`Wow - why bother posting a picture if you're blacking out parts of it. `2.`You are spending 24.6% with the `textView.text = ???.content` call.  What is going on here with the `content` property and won't this be the same for all cells as you don't seem to be accessing a dictionary or array? `3.`You are setting "constants" on each cell every time you you are in this method (delegates, `text`, `font`, layer properties etc...) on every cell and every time. Set these ONCE and don't do them every time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a lot of things going on behind the scenes in an UITableView, that might not make it obvious why it appears unresponsive.

As an example, you should not do tons of work in the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` as the UITableView needs to ask for the height of every single row in your dataset, regardless of whether they are apparent on the screen or not. It does this in order to determine the content size.

It might not at all be your data or your cells that causes the problem. Complex cells with lots of subviews might render slow in the compositor. Especially if you have things like transparency.

Therefore I always put four basic rules down for myself whenever I am implementing a UITableView.

1) Always know what you need to tell the table view when you reload the data. Don't do lot's of stuff in the data source or delegate methods. Have things ready for when UITableView needs it.

2) Don't destroy and create views in the scroll cycle. By that, you should not create new UIView (or whatever) - as an example in your `prepareForReuse` methods. Just reset content of existing views and controls, and then reconfigure them whenever UITableView asks you to.

3) Don't have complex view hierarchies in your cells. Especially transparency and out-of-bounds content that needs to be rendered, can be cumbersome for the compositor to render at fast enough speeds.

4) Don't configure your cells in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Just dequeue and return the cell needed. Always configure and setup your cells in the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method.

That being said, there are some tricks that can help you. As I mentioned above, don't create and destroy views or controls in the cell's `prepareForReuse` method. Don't do heavyweight work at all. Just reset your views and go on. **Which it might sound like you're doing, since it is the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` that causes your troubles.**

Lastly if it is because of compositing (Instruments would show work in some Quartz-related methods) you could succeed by using the `shouldRasterize` and `rasterizationScale` of your cell's CALayer. This can sometimes speed up rendering of cells considerable.

Let me know if any of this stuff makes sense, and if it might have solved your problem.

EDIT:

PS. Yes. Apple did change the text-rendering in iOS 7. But why are you using UITextView?!? I don't know it that well, but I know it is much more heavyweight than UITextField or UILabel. Maybe you could consider using those instead. UITextView is usually for editing something that resembles documents (like the Notes app). **I really think this might be what is causing your troubles.**

Comment: I am using UITextViews because we need to edit this text, I will replace it with UILabel and replace the code in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: to tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: then check the results

Comment: Can't you just use UITextField? That's what I use whenever I need text editing capabilities in a cell. Unless of course you need multi-line capability.

Comment: Yes we need multi-line feature

Comment: Then couldn't you - if you need that - just use an UILabel for displaying the text, and then hide the label and unhide the UITextView whenever the user needs to do edits? Don't know... Just throwing suggestions here...

Comment: that's what i am trying to implement now and check if this will have any impact on performance.

Comment: Thanks very much I replaced the UITextView with UILabel and the performance now going perfect.

Comment: why should we configure in `willDisplayCell` and not `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? I am curious as to why this is more efficient?

Comment: @JTAppleCalendarforiOSSwift Here we go one and a half years later. I think I saw this mentioned in some WWDC video a long time ago. I think with the never faster devices, it is not so important. The reason I can think is, that the table view might request cells it does intent to display immediately - and those cells may never come into view. So doing it in `willDisplayCell` guarantees you only configure cells, that are going into view.